# Setting a shadow on a border-radius div

Tags: css

I have a div with the style as so:

```
.oval {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    border-radius: 250px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And also a background color.

I want to add a shadow to this circle.

Is that possible?

I'm seeing conflicting information, with people saying that's inside the image, so you can't apply any styles to it, and other people suggesting that a style like that exists or there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **[box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)** property:

```css
.oval {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    border-radius: 250px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow:0 0 2px 2px #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval">text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for box shadow:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.67);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.67);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.67);
```

This link explains it: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

And this link lets you experiment with it: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-shadow` property:

```css
.oval {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Box Shadow!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #BC7046;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.circle2{
  box-shadow: -6px -6px 6px #BCAE46;
}

#square {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: #D0DA72;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id=square>
  <div class=circle></div>
  <div class='circle circle2'></div>
</div>
```